# python selenium data extraction

Tags: python, selenium, types, factory

i'm doing a project

```
py
i=0
while i<=3:
    i=i+1
    try:
        
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[ İ value  ]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text
        
    except:
        
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[ İ value  ]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text
    print(a)
```

i want to do it this way, but i couldn't write the i value in the places where it should be written
i'm doing a project

```
i=0
while i<=3:
    i=i+1
    try:
        c=str(i)
        veri=(f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{c}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span')
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,veri).text
        
    except:
        c=str(i)
        veri=(f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{c}]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/h2/a/span')
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,veri).text
    print(a)
```

i tried this bandy, but it didn't happen, i know how to do it, can anyone with knowledge about it help

Comment: Works only in Python 3+   are you using pythoin 2.x? 
Dont need convert it to convert it to string ..use {i} directly

Comment: Please avoid catching the core exception `except:`

Comment: `i=0
while i<=3:
    i=i+1
    try:
        
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text
    except:
        
       
        a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text
       
    print(a)`

error python 3.11.0

Comment: @undetectedSelenium there are two different situations, if div 2 does not find it, it will give an error and div 3 will find it

Comment: Catch _`NoSuchElementException`_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use f string

```
a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'//[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span').text
```

or old style string formatting

```
a=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/div[1]/div[%d]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a/span' % i).text
```